# Am I right or wrong in this absolute value?

Tags: self-learning, coordinate-systems

I had a question to find $p$ which was a co-ordinate in a question where the other coordinates were given and area of triangle was given.

> After simplifying the last equation came as:
>   $$20 = \vert 13p - 20\vert .$$
>   Now $20 = |20| = |-20|$.
>   So $p = 0$ and $p = 40/13$ should be the two answers, but my Maths teacher who only wants students to use her methods and cuts other methods cut $40/13$ and said that only 0 was correct.
>
> I am sure I was right, please tell me whether I am wrong or right.

Edit: I will post the question as soon as I get it. I dont have my question paper now.

Edit: Question reads, "**Find the value of $p$ for which the area of triangle with vertices $A(p, 2p), B (-2,6) and C (3,1) is 10 sq. units$.**

But shouldn't there be infinite values of p? I mean if we take BC as base then we can find many points A with height of triangle same. Please tell me, thank you.

Please answer with whole question solved with proof that I am right so that I can print it. I can print it, right? Or do I need permission? And yes, if you can provide graph in the answer, that will be awesome as well.

Edit: The issue has been resolved. Thank You.

Comment: Without context, there is very little we can say.  Yes, that abstract equation has two solutions, but perhaps the context of the problem shows that we can exclude the solution $p\neq 0$.

Comment: Ask why your solution was wrong.

Comment: Why don’t you put the actual question here

Comment: You are absolutely right!

Comment: It is obvious to see geometrically that there must two triangles which are symmetric to each other with respect to the line (BC) therefore you are totally right

Comment: @GuyFsone sir thank you, but why are there only two answers, there can be infinte points, A for which ABC can have area 10 sq.units.

Comment: @RamKeswani you can see this even form your equation. That equation is like a quadratic equation(just square both side) which therefore cannot have more than two solution

Comment: @RamKeswani If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right indeed.

- for $13p - 20>0 \implies 20 = 13p - 20 \implies p=\frac{40}{13}$
- for $13p - 20<0 \implies 20 = -13p + 20 \implies p=0$

Maybe there is some other motivation to exclude $p=\frac{40}{13}$ depending on the context of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The exclusion of the other solution might be actually motivated by some other context of your exercise **like constrains on $p$** or some previous questions which you did mentioned here. But mathematically both solution are correct as well.

However, you are right but here is one way to get both solution at once solution

$$|13p-20|=20 \Longleftrightarrow (13p-20=20 ~~or ~~~~13p-20=-20) $$

that is $p =0~~or~~~~p =\frac{40}{13}$

### Edit (After OP added missing information):

> **It is obvious to see geometrically that there must two triangles which are symmetric to each other with respect to the line (BC) therefore you are totally right**

Comment: The OP specifically mentions both solutions and is asking why one of them might have been excluded.